# In Javascript how to evaluate expressions if there are other text too

Tags: javascript

I have the following string in javascript

```
var q = "M (95+(4*5)) L (95-(4*5))"
```

I need it to look like

```
"M 115 L 75"
```

Please note that var q could be a very long pattern with multiple M and L. Would anybody know how to accomplish this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: concat the maths?

Comment: There is no way to just do it. You somehow have to parse out the code you want to evaluate.

Comment: You could use template literals so instead of `var q = "M ((95+(4*5)) L ((95-(4*5))"` you could use `var q = \`M ${(95+(4*5))} L ${(95-(4*5))}\``   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: @hajile78 that would assume that OP can manipulate/structure the string before he get's it and he never mentioned that. So i guess we can't just assume that. You need to use regexp or use string-splitting like i wrote in my answer :)

Comment: Note that depending on the real problem, various solutions might be preferred. More precision seems needed.

Comment: I would not do it, but `q.replace(/([\(\)\d\-\+\/\*]*)/g, m => m && eval(m))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a sane and reliable way to do it, without resorting to `eval`:

```js
var q = "M (95+(4*5)) L (95.3-(4*5))"

let res = (function fix(input){
  let output = input.replace(/\(\s*(-?[\d.]+)\s*([*+-])\s*(-?[\d.]+)\s*\)/g, function(_, a, op, b){
     switch(op){
     case '+': return +a + +b;
     case '-': return a - b;
     case '*': return a * b;
     default: return "_";
     }
   });
   return input==output ? input : fix(output);
})(q);

console.log("res=", res);
```

The idea is simply to replace all `( number operator number )` until there's nothing to replace.

Note that this would also work for more complex expressions (I assume you're building a SVG path) and wouldn't break at the first added space.

Comment: A way more clean and easy way is to use "eval" because "eval" is made exactly for those scenarios :)

Comment: I disagree @spyro, this is really nice because it won't `eval` arbitrary code.

Comment: @spyro let's forget all the risks related to evaluating arbitrary code. Write the eval version and you'll see it's not really clearer (if you handle various cases) and is much slower.

Comment: This does not work for `"M (1+2*3)"` or other types of expressions.

Comment: @cgTag this could be supported but I don't think it's desirable according to the question

Comment: @DenysSéguret @MarkMeyer OP didn't said that the string comes from an untrusted source. You should lever eval untrusted code. But since that's not the question here, the `eval` function fits the needs perfectly. OP also didn't said that the mathematical functions are limited to the provided example so you have to implement every possible mathematical edge-case if you are coding some manual evaluation.

Comment: @spyro that's why I said *"let's forget all the risks related to evaluating arbitrary code"* : I agree that OP may not have this concern (let's hope the code isn't used later with an inputted string). To anybody tempted by an eval: please at least check you don't have any other chars that [*+-\d()] before launching it!

Comment: @DenysSéguret sorry if i got you wrong there, i am not native. I thought you were writing this in an ironic meaning. As you can see, i already edited my given answer. OP can still think of some ways to speed things up if the string is really long and eval is too slow (never did speed-comparison with it) but then again, if other mathematical expressions may show up in the string, the tradeoff would maybe be maybe in favour of using eval. But we can't say that for sure since we don't know the detailed project. Can you tell me if my corrected answer fits your concerns of using "eval"?

Comment: @ Denys Séguret..Thank you for the solution. Yes I am using it to build a svg path. But the code doesn't work if I have decimals.. like if I have var q = "M (95+(4.5*5)) L (95-(4*5))"

Comment: @Aparna I added the dot to the regex. But I suggest you take the time to read it and understand it, as you may want to change your requirements later (note that I willingly didn't add a division).

Comment: @ Denys Séguret thankyou very much!!..yes I will take the time out to understand the code..thankyou once again

Answer (score 2):

You could take `M` and `L` as marker and take only the part between for `eval`.

```js
var q = "M (95+(4*5)) L (95-(4*5))";

q = q.replace(/([ML])(.*?)(?=[ML]|$)/g, (_, a, b) => a + ' ' + eval(b) +' ');

console.log(q);
```

Comment: Just a note (which may matter or not, depending on OP's goal): This string looks a little like it was built for a SVG path, in which case longer strings and several numbers per letter might be needed.

Comment: @DenysSéguret was my thought too, since the pattern looks alike. But with this short example and no hint about where it comes from, we have to assume that it's maybe not SVG.

Comment: Also please note, that using `eval` on untrusted code is a security risk. But since OP didn't said anything about it, this answer stays valid until further information of OP. Also, i answered the same thing 6 minutes before your answer ;)

Answer (score -2):

You need fix parenthesis

```js
  let str = "M (95+(4*5)) L (95-(4*5))";
  
  let res = str.split(" ").map(e=>{
    try{
      return eval(e);
    }catch(err){
      return e;
    }
  }).join(" ");
  
  console.log(res)
```

Comment: You forgot to `join`.

Answer (score -2):

If the initial string is always formated in this way i would split then eval when the element is not a reserved char

```
var q = 'M (95+(4*5)) L (95-(4*5))'

let processed = ''
let arr = q.split(' ')

arr.forEach(a => {
  if (a !== 'M' && a !== 'L') {
    a = eval(a)
  }
  processed = processed.concat(a, ' ')
})
# Now proccessed is 'M 115 L 75 ' you can trim and remove extra space
processed = processed.trim()
```

I don't recommend using this if you will be using this on client-side, because as others said this can be changed via F12.

But if you will be using this only at server-side with controlled inputs, then it's not a problem.

Comment: Even on server-side, `eval()`-ing user input is dangerous.

Comment: thats why i said: _with controlled inputs_

Answer (score -5):

Edit: For future readers: My solution was downvoted by users that think that using `eval()` is a security risk. And they are correct that evaluating untrusted code, is a risk. But since OP didn't said anything about the source beeing untrusted, my solution is still valid until OP clarifies that the string-source is indeed untrusted.

The solution, in my opinion, is a 2-way solution:

First, use regular expressions to group the string into one letter (like "M") and the rest until the next letter.

You may also use an easier approach by string-splitting at the letters (like "M" and "L").

Regardless of which way you choose, you get an array of objects with each entry having a letter and some math-string.

You can simply `eval()` the math-sting (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) and get the result.

This is not too hard in my opinion but it's some nice way to get into string-splitting and "eval" :)

Comment: Maybe those people who downvote a valid answer, could be nice enough to comment on it, why it's downvoted. Stackoverflow is a place where we should exchange information and knowledge and regarding the "eval"-risk i already edited my answer. If you don't directly assume untrusted code in the string, using "eval" is totally fine. If not, please be kind enpigh to provide further information on why my answer is not valid/good in your opinion.

Comment: it's not a valid answer. Eval can be changed - especially client-side eval.

Comment: @treyBake what do you mean with "can be changed" and why do you assume this? OP didn't say one thing about where he wants to execute this code. If you are going to complain about the possibility of a function beeing overwritten then you have to assume that every function is overwritten and then you can not use reged either because it could be overwritten. If you were hinting to something different, please speficy. If there are other reasonf for not using eval, me and others will appreciate your answer.

Comment: hit f12 - now you have the console and can manipulate the JS - hence eval, especially client-side, is evil. That doesn't matter. Always practice the safest, best option - not the easiest.

Comment: @treyBake browser ececute JS in their VM/runtime, yes. But this applied to all JS-code. I can just embed my own JS-file into google.de with the developer-tools. But that doesn't affect a server. How would it be a security risk if i embed my own JS-file into your website by using the developer tools? All JS-execution only is executed ony my own machine and the parsed webpage, not your server.

Comment: By talking to the server - good server-side code will protect against eval and user input like this. Hence why, database connections aren't done via client-side. And it can execute on the server, if you have cookies/sessions you can use this against the server to trick it into performing actions. Again, hence why eval should be avoided

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186125/discussion-between-spyro-and-treybake).

Comment: I think it's best to assume that input data is untrustworthy unless indicated otherwise. Doing it the other way around can easily lead to security problems.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Why didn't you answer in the stackoverflow-chat i just linked in my previous comment? Please don't spam the comment section with needless comments. But since you now wrote here: Please read the question again. No question asked here is about security. Don't assume you know what OP's project looks like. OP asked for a methode to evaulate a mathematical string. The `eval()` function is sufficient for that. Period. The fact that no programmer should trust a string that came from external sources/user, is known to 100% of the people here and needs no further explanation.